# Rules to change words

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), keywords = c("google, yahoo, air, cookie", "cookie, air"))
```

I would like to implement rules like the following:

```
stocks <- c("google, yahoo")
climate <- c("air")
cuisine <- c("cookie")
```

and take the results like this:

```
df_ne <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), keywords = c("stocks, climate, cuisine", "climate, cuisine")
```

How is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked the cholland answer (+1), but you can also use `tidytext::unnest_tokens()`, that is going to be easier imho if you're goint to have many more than six words.

First you can create a mapping df:

```
mapped <- rbind (data.frame(word_a = stocks, type = "stock", stringsAsFactors = F),
                 data.frame(word_a = climate, type = "climate", stringsAsFactors = F),
                 data.frame(word_a = cuisine, type = "cuisine", stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Now you can use the mentioned function to have a couple of unnested df to reach the goal:

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
mapped <- mapped %>%  unnest_tokens(word, word_a)

df %>% 
unnest_tokens(word, keywords) %>%    # split words
left_join(mapped) %>%                # join to map
group_by(id) %>%                     # group
summarise(keywords = str_c(unique(type), collapse = ",")) # collapse the word (unique)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id keywords             
  <dbl> <chr>                
1     1 stock,climate,cuisine
2     2 cuisine,climate
```

Note the second row has inverted words rather than your expected output due they are in that order the corrispondent words in the first `df`.

---

With data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), keywords = c("google, yahoo, air, cookie", "cookie, air"), stringsAsFactors = F)


stocks <- c("google, yahoo")
climate <- c("air")
cuisine <- c("cookie")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), keywords = c("google, yahoo, air, cookie", "cookie, air"))

df %>% 
  mutate(keywords = str_replace_all(keywords, 
    c("google, yahoo" = "stocks","air" = "climate", "cookie" = "cuisine")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naïve solution to start with :

```
key <- list(
  stocks = c("google", "yahoo"),
  climate = "air",
  cuisine = "cookie"
)

df2 <- df
#replace by the key
for (k in 1:length(key)){
  for(sk in key[[k]]){
    df2$keywords <- gsub(sk, names(key)[k], df2$keywords, fixed = TRUE)
  }
}
#remove duplicated items
df2$keywords <- lapply(strsplit(df2$keywords, ", "), function(l) paste(unique(l), sep = ","))
```